# How to search for a string in a list and output all the values that contain the string?

Tags: python

I want to be able to see if a string is in my list and then print all off the items in the list which contain the string.

I found `[s for s in y if any(xs in s for xs in topcolour)]` to use and this worked perfectly when I was only looking for numbers in the list but when I tried looking for a colour (blue, red, yellow or green) it tells me the colour can be found and then just prints out the whole list instead of the individual items in the list like it did for the numbers. FYI p1card, topnumber and topcolour changes every game.

```
if any(topnumber in s for s in p1cards):
    matching = [s for s in p1cards if any(xs in s for xs in topnumber)]
    print(matching) #this one works

elif any(topcolour  in s for s in p1cards):
    matching = [s for s in p1cards if any(xs in s for xs in topcolour)]
    print(matching) #this one doesn't work
```

The first block of code outputs the exact item in the list if it can be found for example `["Blue 7"]` if the topnumber was 7 but when im trying to search by colour it would just output the whole list.

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: An example of what is printed?

Comment: Your code has an `elif`.  If the first matches, the second one will not.

Comment: Thank you for replying but I tried putting the code on its own in a separate programme without any if statements and it still didnt work.

Comment: Please show us sample content of `topnumber`, `topcolour` and `p1cards`.

Comment: Another potential issue here is `y`.  Is that a copy of p1cards from a past life?

Comment: Top number could be anything between 0 to 9, topcolour could be Blue, Red, Yellow or Green and p1cards would be something like {'Pick colour', 'Red 1', 'Yellow 5', 'Red 9', 'Blue skip', 'Blue 6'} because its 7 seven random uno cards.

Comment: Oh yeah, thank you. I have changed the ys to p1cards in this post. In my real code it is saved as y because it was in a function but I changed it p1cards because I though it would be easier to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without explicit examples of input and output, it's hard to tell if this is exactly what you're trying to do, but I think it works based on what you've provided.

I personally find nested comprehensions really hard to read, and you don't need them for this. [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) is a nice [functional](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/functional.html) method of retrieving members of a collection that fulfill specific criteria. [`lambda`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#lambda) isn't necessary -- you could just define one-line functions and pass them as the first argument -- but it's good for very simple test like this.

```
p1cards = {'Pick colour', 'Red 1', 'Yellow 5', 'Red 9', 'Blue skip', 'Blue 6'}

topnumber = '9'

print(tuple(
    filter(
        lambda c: topnumber in c,
        p1cards,
    )
))

topcolour = 'Red'

print(tuple(
    filter(
        lambda c: topcolour in c,
        p1cards,
    )
))
```

Output:

```
('Red 9',)
('Red 1', 'Red 9')
```

*Note: The `tuple` calls are just for display. If you run this in Python 2.x, you don't need them; in 3.x, you won't get useful output without them.*